# I am a new to test automation and am using Playwright with JS

Tags: na

I am new to the test automation field and am using Playwright with JS. I struggle to access the web element when it has the same HTML Attributes for two different web elements[Web-Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czX16.jpg). Pls, advise me on the best way to access the web element. Pls, find the attached Pic. IN that, I want to access the first order ID

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Playwright is strict library, it means you can't handle selector which share class, id etc. with other element. Good practice is using

```
page.locator("Your selector").click()/.fill("Text").
```

Also the good practice is using

```
data-testid="Some-locator"
```

(https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-data-testid-attribute-in-testing). So ask your developer to put ids on elements.